# Log messages not displayed

Tags: logging

It seems like the substrate [client::cli::init](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.26/client/cli/src/lib.rs#L240) code is not properly initializing the logger: any `log::info!` calls (or even `log::error!` calls) are not being shown in the terminal. All `println!` outputs *are* being shown fwiw. The init code is called by [client::cli::create_runner](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/polkadot-v0.9.26/client/cli/src/lib.rs#L199), and I am starting the node with `RUST_LOG=info`. I also tried the various logging options such as the `--tracing-targets`, but to no avail.

The reason why I think there is going something wrong in the initialization, is because if I call `env_logger::init()` prior to `create_runner`, my logs *do* work, but obviously that will cause `create_runner` to fail when it tries to initialize the logger again.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node startup message missing after upgrade to Polkadot v0.9.23](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/node-startup-message-missing-after-upgrade-to-polkadot-v0-9-23)

Answer (score 2):

I think that version (v0.9.26) have a version of `tracing-core` as dep that cause the issue. You can fix it by pin the crate version

```
tracing-core = "=0.1.26"
```

Or update to `v0.9.28` where the issue is already fixed.
Thanks!