# How to generate node information?

Tags: substrateinterface, cli

[image]

How can i generate this information while starting my chain???

Comment: What command are you using to start your chain?

Comment: ./target/release/substrate --dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the "startup messages" show again, I had to fix the dependency of

> tracing-core
>
> **cargo update -p tracing-core --precise 0.1.28**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if `sc_cli` provides these. AFAIK it didn't.

---

But here is a general solution.

Check this https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/12f3123d8c4d6fb8896d3f42dadb7b99a168fde1/cli/src/command.rs#L117-L122.

You could put any log in your startup function.

Example:

> https://github.com/zsiciarz/rust-cpuid

```rust
match cpuid::identify() {
    Ok(info) => {
        log::info!("Found: {} CPU, model: {}", info.vendor, info.codename);
        log::info!("The full brand string is: {}", info.brand);
        log::info!("Hardware AES support: {}", if info.has_feature(cpuid::CpuFeature::AES) { "yes" } else { "no" });
    },
    Err(err) => log::info!("cpuid error: {}", err),
};
match cpuid::clock_frequency() {
    Some(frequency) => log::info!("CPU speed: {} MHz", frequency),
    None => log::info!("Couldn't get CPU speed."),
};
```

---

Now, I think the question duplicates with [Node startup message missing after upgrade to Polkadot v0.9.23](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/node-startup-message-missing-after-upgrade-to-polkadot-v0-9-23?noredirect=1&lq=1).